# Nested forms dont work in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rails-admin

Brand **has many** images is my association. Image uses paperclip

In Rails Admin, I want to add images when i add a brand

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :images, as=> :imageable
end

class Image < ActiveRecord:Base
  attr_accessor :image_thumb
  attr_accessible :image, :imageable_id, :imageable_type, :image_thumb
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

But this is what i get

[image]

***How can i achieve my goal?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to add attr_accessible

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :images_attributes
    has_many :products
    has_many :images, :as => :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Comment: Has this been addressed for Rails 4 now that attr_accessible is deprecated?

Comment: I do that ... accepts_nested_attributes and attr_accessible but doesn't show nested model in rails admin !! 
it's show button add new instance only !!!
what should i do !?

Answer (score 0):

And solution is when you user acts_as_taggable, to add to your rails_admin.rb config file next code:

```
field :tag_list do
  label "Tag"
end
```

Or 'image_list', depends on what you are use.